# Nhibernate QueryOver: How to reference property in a mapped component

Tags: nhibernate

We have a component mapped like this:

```
Map(x => x.EffectiveDates)
.Columns
.Add(new[] { "EffDt", "ExpDt" })
.CustomType(typeof(DateRangeUserType));
```

and I want to do something like this

```
_session
.QueryOver<Agreement>()
.Where(a => a.EffectiveDates.Start >= now 
         && a.EffectiveDates.End <= now)
```

but I cannot. It fails with error

> could not resolve property: EffectiveDates.Start

How can this be achieved with `QueryOver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails because of the use of CustomType in the mapping. If it is mapped just as component then it works fine.

```
 Component(x => x.EffectiveDates, m =>
        {
             m.Map(x => x.Start, "EffDt");
             m.Map(x => x.End, "ExpDt");
        });
```